# How to fix permission errors with npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to create a new React app but am running into permission errors that I don't understand. I'm pretty new to programming so I don't quite understand what's going on. Below is a copy of my terminal. I am using a Mac with Mojave version 10.14.6. I have Node v10.15.3 installed npm 6.9.0 and npx 6.9.0.

I've had other permission errors before and have used sudo to get around them, but I would really like to know what the root cause of these permission errors is and how to fix it.

> Monicas-MacBook-Air:code monica$ npx create-react-app weekly-scheduler
>
> Creating a new React app in /Users/monica/code/weekly-scheduler.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing
>   react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
>
> npm ERR! path
>   /Users/monica/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/67/c7/8dd80b7495bd43b4dedc63a0cbc936eed1bb997cd36191f55d47f11693a4 npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! errno -13 npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR!
>   Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
>   '/Users/monica/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/67/c7/8dd80b7495bd43b4dedc63a0cbc936eed1bb997cd36191f55d47f11693a4'
>   npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
>   '/Users/monica/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/67/c7/8dd80b7495bd43b4dedc63a0cbc936eed1bb997cd36191f55d47f11693a4']
>   npm ERR!   cause: npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
>   '/Users/monica/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/67/c7/8dd80b7495bd43b4dedc63a0cbc936eed1bb997cd36191f55d47f11693a4'
>   npm ERR!      errno: -13, npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!
>   syscall: 'open', npm ERR!      path: npm ERR!
>   '/Users/monica/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/67/c7/8dd80b7495bd43b4dedc63a0cbc936eed1bb997cd36191f55d47f11693a4'
>   }, npm ERR!   isOperational: true, npm ERR!   stack: npm ERR!
>   'Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
>   \'/Users/monica/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/67/c7/8dd80b7495bd43b4dedc63a0cbc936eed1bb997cd36191f55d47f11693a4\'',
>   npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall:
>   'open', npm ERR!   path: npm ERR!
>   '/Users/monica/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/67/c7/8dd80b7495bd43b4dedc63a0cbc936eed1bb997cd36191f55d47f11693a4',
>   npm ERR!   parent: '@babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex' }
>   npm ERR!  npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating
>   system. npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to
>   access this file as the current user npm ERR!  npm ERR! If you believe
>   this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the npm ERR!
>   permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
>   npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not
>   recommended).
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/monica/.npm/_logs/2019-12-06T20_36_41_071Z-debug.log
>
> Aborting installation.   npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel
>   error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.
>
> Deleting generated file... package.json Deleting weekly-scheduler/
>   from /Users/monica/code Done.

Comment: Npx tries to install the packages before running them. Unfortunately, the directory `/Users/monica/.npm/` seems to be protected. See https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally for some fixes.

Comment: And also https://gilbitron.me/blog/fixing-npm-eacces-error-on-os-x-b0dd1dfc7e9/ (which basically just re-perms `~/.npm`). If you `sudo`ed any of the base apps it can sometimes get a little wonky.